# How to "like" and "comment" on facebook through Graph API in iPhone?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am displaying news feed  using graph api. I have queries about below problems.

1. I would like to give "Like" functionality for each news feed post.
2. I would like to give "Comment" functionality for each news feed post.

Can someone assist me how to solve this problem using either graph api in iphone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859283/integrate-comments-with-facebook-ios-sdk-iphone/16320067#16320067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to my answer here: [How to comment or like a photo in facebook through FBconnect or Graph API in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957260/how-to-comment-or-like-a-photo-in-facebook-through-fbconnect-or-graph-api-in-ipho/4957872#4957872)

Just post your Access Token to https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_THE_POST/likes or your Access Token and the Message as a parameter to https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_THE_POST/comments.

For more info see the "Publishing" part in the Facebook Documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api