# Integrate Comments with Facebook iOS SDK (iPhone)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I implemented the Facebook iOS API / SDK into my application and it works fine. I'm e.g. able to read the name of the logged in user etc.

**So the question:**

I have several view Controllers with videos in it. The user is logged in with his Facebook account and should be able to post a comment or like the video. Other users should be able to see the previous comments as a list.

I already created a Facebook application on `Facebook.com`.

What should I do next? Do I have to do create some "lists" on Facebook.com which I can `GET` and display via the `Facebook API`?

Comment: Hey, so what was the conclusion to this question? I wish to implement a similar comments and likes function to my application as well. Similar to instangram comments and likes. I have been reading up on the APIs and have managed to do a login, retrieving user info etc, but I'm still quite unsure of how to integrate comments and likes. I wish to allow user to post a comment or like a certain post or picture in my app, which is not a post that is existent on facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial for [facebook on iphone](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

EDIT : 
Ok, about the list I think it will be best if you store it in the user's device (or preferably a remote database) because keeping track of user comments specific to your application through facebook is too cumbersome (I am not familiar with FB API which returns a list of comments for a specific app so check that as well)

Posting to the User’s Wall is easy and well explained [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app) (Goto "Posting to the User’s Wall" somewhere in the middle of the page).

Comment: Yeah, that was the one I was following the whole time but since it's my first time dealing with the FB API could you maybe give me a hint what I should search for? Maybe one word I could type into the search?!

Comment: @Darwin I have added more details with a link for posting to facebook

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *res = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is my comment", @"message", YOUR ACCESS TOKEN,@"access_token",nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/comments",PHOTO'S ID] parameters:res HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ok!! %@",result);
    }
}];
```

Comment: You shouldn't post the same answer to multiple questions (5 so far) when they don't really answer the question that was asked. If an answer is suited for more than one question, then one of those questions should probably be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Ren ples check all question. question are logically same