# Like a post on a Facebook page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am building an imdb (for movies) app for iOS that communicates with the imdb facebook page. I realize there are some already out there but without giving too much away, mine will be different.

I have figured out how to post a like on somebody else's wall post on that page via the Graph explorer. It is simply

```
/[postID]/likes         using a  POST request and having the right permissions.
```

I realize that I could make this request via a NSURL Connection. But I am almost sure that there is built in request using the iOS Facebook SDK (3.8, most recent). I am very confused how to go about this, the documentation in my opinion is very confusing. I did the research and some people did it via FBRequestConnection but then others said that was not allowed anymore.

So does anyone know how I can like a Facebook post via the Facebook iOS SDK (3.8)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721057/how-to-like-and-comment-on-facebook-through-graph-api-in-iphone

Comment: @StuartM Perfect Stuart! Wow I feel dumb for not finding it, answers my question exactly! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer here - [How to "like" and "comment" on facebook through Graph API in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721057/how-to-like-and-comment-on-facebook-through-graph-api-in-iphone)

> Please refer to my answer here: How to comment or like a photo in facebook through FBconnect or Graph API in iPhone SDK ?
>
> Just post your Access Token to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_THE_POST/likes or your Access Token
>   and the Message as a parameter to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_THE_POST/comments.
>
> For more info see the "Publishing" part in the Facebook Documentation:
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/users/432565/audience